# jquery not changing the dropdown element class?

Tags: jquery

Here is the dropdown.All i want is to pick the selected option id.THANKS IN ADVANCE.

```
        <select id="addbtype" name="addbtype" style="margin-bottom:0px;width:130px;">
            <option class='type_selected1' id='qtype_1'>restaurant</option>
            <option  id='qtype_2'>clothings</option>
            <option  id='qtype_8'>paints</option>
        </select>
        <script> 
        $('#addbtype option').click(function(){
            if(!$(this).hasClass('type_selected1')) 
            {
                var active_element = document.getElementsByClassName('type_selected1');
                $(active_element).removeClass('type_selected1');
                $(this).addClass('type_selected1');
            }
        });

        var qtid = $('.type_secelcted').attr('id').split('_')[1];
    </script>
```

Comment: I am getting the same id qtype_1 irrespective of whatever i have selected @ Milind Anantwar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it, You can get the "id".

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    qtid = ''
$('#addbtype').change(function(){

    $('#addbtype option').removeClass('type_selected1')
   var qtid = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id").split('_')[1]
 $(this).children(":selected").addClass('type_selected1')
});

$('#pickid').click(function(){


    alert($('.type_selected1').attr("id").split('_')[1])
});

    })
```

**HTML:**

```
    <select id="addbtype" name="addbtype" style="margin-bottom:0px;width:130px;">
    <option class='type_selected1' id='qtype_1'>restaurant</option>
    <option  id='qtype_2'>clothings</option>
    <option  id='qtype_8'>paints</option>
</select>

<button id="pickid">pickid</button>
```

Here is demo link http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/ZuBAj/1/

Comment: Actually i need to send the selected option id via ajax on click of a button.can u help me..previously i was changing the class and picking the selected option id.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `.change()` for dropdown:

```
$('#addbtype').change(function(){
  if(!$(this).find(':selected').hasClass('type_selected1')) 
    {
    var active_element = document.getElementsByClassName('type_selected1');
    $(active_element).removeClass('type_selected1');
    $(this).addClass('type_selected1');
   }
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4624/1/)**

Comment: I am not getting the selected elements id instead i am getting the first id whatever i select.

Comment: to get selected option,use `$(this).val()`

Comment: I dont want the value i want its id

Comment: use `$(this).children(":selected").attr("id")`

Answer (score 0):

For what you use this class? If you use it for styling only, you doesn't need it and can type

```
#addtype option[selected] {
//here your css
}
```

if you want to get selected option's value -

```
$('#addbtype').change(function(){ 
  var selectedValue = $(this).val();
});
```

For selected option's id -

```
$('#addbtype').change(function(){ 
   var selectedItem = $(this).find(":selected");
   alert(selectedItem[0].id);
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/k4624/2/

Comment: i want to get selected option id

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#addbtype").change(function () {

            alert($(this).children(":selected").attr("id"));
        });
```

Comment: Actually i need to send the selected option id via ajax on click of a buttonpreviously i was changing the class and picking the selected option id.